# SQL Query on dependency of a column

Tags: sql

I have to write a query for a  table where I have two columns lets say id1 and id2. In this query i have to ensure that id2 can have atmost three values for a single id1. I have tried using this query:

```
select id1,id2
from table
group by id1,id2
having count(id2)<=3
```

I am not getting the result through this query..any modifications?

Comment: Did you mean at most or at least? Your query is getting _at least_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (`id1`, `id2`) pairs aren't unique, then maybe like this:

```
SELECT t.id1, t.id2
FROM atable t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id1
    FROM atable
    GROUP BY id1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id2) <= 3
  ) g ON t.id1 = g.id1
GROUP BY t.id1, t.id2
```

But if the pairs *are* unique, then the outer query doesn't need GROUP BY and the inner query doesn't need DISTINCT:

```
SELECT t.id1, t.id2
FROM atable t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id1
    FROM atable
    GROUP BY id1
    HAVING COUNT(id2) <= 3
  ) g ON t.id1 = g.id1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand... Maybe this?

```
select id1, id2 from table where (select count(id2) from table where id1 = id1) <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this....

select a.id1,a.id2 
from 
table_name a,(select count(1),id1 from table_name a group by id1 having count(*)<=3) b
where a.id1=b.id1 
order by id1

Answer (score 0):

It is more typical to test for rows that *fail* the business rule e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM Table1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT T1.id1
                 FROM Table1 AS T1
                WHERE T1.id1 = Table1.id1
                GROUP 
                   BY T1.id1
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
              );
```

The idea is that once you have decided which rows violate the business rule and have you have scrubbed the bad data, you want to put in place a constraint to ensure the rule is not violated in the future e.g. (notice the same query construct):

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD
   CONSTRAINT atmost_three_id2_values_for_a_single_id1
      CHECK (NOT EXISTS (
                         SELECT T1.id1
                           FROM Table1 AS T1
                          WHERE T1.id1 = Table1.id1
                          GROUP 
                             BY T1.id1
                         HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
                        ));
```

Sadly, [your SQL product of choice probably does not support subqueries in `CHECK` constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368349/why-dont-dbmss-support-assertion/6372101#6372101). You can 'design away' the need for a table-level constraint by adding a sequence number column, allowing you to use commonly-found `UNIQUE` and column-level `CHECK` constraints e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
 id1 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 id2 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 UNIQUE (id1, id2), 
 seq INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
    CHECK (seq BETWEEN 1 AND 3), 
 UNIQUE (id1, seq)
);
```