# SQL Sub queries in check constraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key-relationship, plpgsql, check-constraints

Can I make SQL sub queries in Check constraint ?

I've a `post` table with columns `id, owner`
I've another table `action` with columns `user_id, post_id`
Table `user` with columns `id`

`post_id -> post.id` and `user_id -> user.id` also `post.owner -> user.id`

Now I want to constraint `post(post_id).id != user_id` on table `action`

How is that possible ?

Comment: Why should it matter if a column that references one table happens to have a *value* that is present in another table?  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: So,IIUC if for instance the *action* is *upvote*, you basically want to prevent a user upvoting **their own** *post* ?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It is not supported to look beyond the current row in a CHECK constraint.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-createtable.html says:

> A check constraint specified as a column constraint should reference
>   that column's value only, while an expression appearing in a table
>   constraint can reference multiple columns.
>
> Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to
>   variables other than columns of the current row.

There are good reasons for this restriction, but if you like to juggle flaming torches while riding a unicycle through heavy traffic, you can subvert the restriction using functions.  The situations in which this will *not* come back to bite you are rare; you would be much safer to enforce the invariant in trigger code instead.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/triggers.html

Comment: Per [Tom Lane's comment](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/13340.1271686859@sss.pgh.pa.us), hacking around the subquery restriction is not advised: _"CHECK is meant to handle constraints on a row's value **in isolation**. If you try to use it to enforce cross-row conditions, the project will certainly end badly._

Comment: Yes, this is true: "CHECK is meant to handle constraints on a row's value in isolation." ... But: what is a unique constraint? Is it "juggle flaming torches while riding a unicycle through heavy traffic"? BTW I already tried both juggling flaming torches and riding a unicycle. Up to now I can't do both at one, but maybe in the future.

Comment: "It is not supported to look beyond the current row in a **`CHECK`** constraint."  Obviously, other types of constraints (i.e., `UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY`, `EXCLUDE`) must look beyond the single row.

Comment: Very useful! Out of curiosity, *why* would this end badly?

Comment: The reason that a cross-row reference in a `CHECK` constraint would end badly is that the constraint is only evaluated for the modified row.  So, while it would generally work _at first_, when the other referenced row was modified in a way that invalidated the constraint, that would not be noticed.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to use a before insert/update trigger that does the check, and if it fails it should raise an exception, which will roll-out the whole insertion/update... if it passes, then the insertion/update is executed.