# Table level constraint to prevent overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Below is the schema where I need to put a constraint such that a second new entry could be put in for a room number, even before the existing depDt for the same room number. Could any of you please help me with this??

```
CREATE TABLE Accomodation (
  roomNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
  arrDt DATE NOT NULL,
  depDt DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (roomNo, arrDt), 
  CONSTRAINT date_chk CHECK (arrDt < depDt)
);

INSERT INTO HotelStays(roomNo, arrDt, depDt) VALUES 
  (123, to_date('20160202', 'YYYYMMDD'),to_date('20160206','YYYYMMDD')),
  (123, to_date('20160205', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160208','YYYYMMDD'));
```

I have tried giving a sub query under WHERE in CONSTRAINTS but its is not working in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: You're missing `)` at the end of second element in `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Sorry but thats a typo.

Comment: From what I see a second entry with the same room number __can__ be inserted as long as their date of arrival is different. What is your actual problem? Could you show the expected output and errors or the output you are receiving?

Comment: Please fix the naming of your columns as well. I doubt that `roomNum` and `roomNo` are any different. The same with `arrDt` and `arrDate`

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11d34d/1

Comment: follow the above link you will see the whole schema and table. same room number can be inserted as long as the date of arrival will not fall in between arrival date and departure date of the existing room number

Comment: You need a trigger to implement what you want. A `CHECK` constraint can look only at fields of the *same* row. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179121/sql-sub-queries-in-check-constraint).

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: no you don't need a trigger. A simple exclusion constraint will do

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't know such a thing existed in postgresql.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using an [exclusion constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT) on the date range:

```
alter table Accomodation
  add constraint no_overlap 
  exclude using gist (roomno with =, daterange(arrdt, depdt) with &&);
```

Note that you need the [btree_gist extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) to support the `=` operator in a GiST index.

Comment: SQL Fiddle doesn't have this extension.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This does not solve the problem of race conditions.

Create a function that checks whether a room is available based on your conditions and returns a scalar boolean value which can be used in `CHECK` constraint.

Here you can preview how it works (remember to uncomment the last insert statement):[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e349f)

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_room_available(int, date)
RETURNS boolean
STABLE
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Accomodation WHERE roomNo = $1 AND $2 BETWEEN arrDt AND depDt ) THEN
    RETURN false;
  END IF;

  RETURN true;
END;
$$;
```

Create table with new constraint

```
CREATE TABLE Accomodation (
  roomNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
  arrDt DATE NOT NULL,
  depDt DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (roomNo, arrDt), 
  CONSTRAINT date_chk CHECK (arrDt<depDt),
  CONSTRAINT room_avail CHECK (is_room_available(roomNo, arrDt)) -- added
  );
```

Try inserting two rows in separate statements

```
INSERT INTO Accomodation(roomNo, arrDt, depDt)
VALUES 
(123, to_date('20160202', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160206','YYYYMMDD'));

INSERT INTO Accomodation(roomNo, arrDt, depDt)
VALUES 
(123, to_date('20160205', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160208','YYYYMMDD'));
```

First value is inserted, while when issuing the second insert statement you get a **check constraint violation**

> ERROR: new row for relation "accomodation" violates check constraint "room_avail" Detail: Failing row contains (123, 2016-02-05, 2016-02-08).

**Note**: This could be easily implemented using triggers as well. You just need to modify the function a little and issue a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Comment: What does $$ means? Why have you used GO terminator?

Comment: @Shashikiran: the `$$` is called dollar quoting: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Comment: @Shashikiran I used GO as terminator in SQL Fiddle to be able to use `;` inside a function without error. Normally this is the terminator there and would yield errors assuming for example `END IF;` to be invalid statement.

Comment: it is not working for multiple insert statements
INSERT INTO Accomodation(roomNo, arrDt, depDt)
VALUES 
(123, to_date('20160202', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160206','YYYYMMDD')),
(123, to_date('20160205', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160208','YYYYMMDD'))
GO

Comment: @Shashikiran I've mentioned that you need to insert two rows in separate statements in my answer. And why would your application build multiple inserts into one statement anyway?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I was trying different things before incorporating in the code. And also could you please explain this SELECT query "SELECT 1 FROM Accomodation WHERE roomNo = $1 AND $2 BETWEEN arrDt AND depDt".
I didn't understand $1 and $2 part

Comment: `$1` and `$2` are variables storing input arguments for a function. Here `$1` is for `int` value, the first argument - which is a `roomNo` and `$2` is for `date` value - the date to be checked for overlaps.

Comment: Thanks. I was little confused as I had to modify the depdate overlap constraint. Now I got it