# SQLAlchemy Check Constraint With Join

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have created a many to many relationship in SQLAlchemy using something like this:

```
b_c = Table('b_c', 
            Column('b_id', UUIDType(binary=False), ForeignKey('b.id'), primary_key=True),
            Column('c_id', UUIDType(binary=False), ForeignKey('c.id'), primary_key=True)
           )
```

Where `c` and `b` are tables with only an `id` column (`UUIDType(binary=false)`) and the models similar to this:

```
class A(object):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column('id', UUIDType(binary=False), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)

class B(object):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column('id', UUIDType(binary=False), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(UUIDType(binary=False), ForeignKey('a.id'), nullable=False)
    a = relationship('A')

class C(object):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id = Column('id', UUIDType(binary=False), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(UUIDType(binary=False), ForeignKey('a.id'), nullable=False)
    a = relationship('A')
```

This relationship works perfectly fine, and I'm able to filter the B and C objects to a parent A for my usage scenario. However, to ensure integrity of the data beyond the logic that uses these models, is there any best practice for requiring that for any relation `b_c`, `b.a` must equal `c.a` ?

Apologies if this is answered elsehwere, but any examples I have found are simple CHECK constraints against values in the table itself, and nothing requiring values of joined tables.

Comment: why do `A` & `C` subclass `object` instead of `Model`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, missed that when trying to remove some of the unnecessary details - Updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation:

> [Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row. The system column tableoid may be referenced, but not any other system column.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

What you are describing cannot be done via check constraints, but may be achieved via sql triggers before insert or update:

Here's a postgresql function & trigger definition to check for equality of the referred table's `a_id` foreign key.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ckref_b_c() RETURNS trigger AS $ckref_b_c$
  DECLARE
  bid uuid;
  cid uuid;
  BEGIN
    select a_id INTO bid FROM b WHERE id = NEW.b_id;
    select a_id INTO cid FROM c WHERE id = NEW.c_id;
    IF bid != cid THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'associated records do not refer to same parent in `a`';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
 $ckref_b_c$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ckref_b_c BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON b_c
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ckref_b_c();
```

You can execute these queries through the sqlalchemy engine after the tables are created. Sqlalchemy also has an event system which you could use to emit these queries automatically.

Comment: I think you've nailed it. As I was looking into this more today, it definitely felt like I was going down a very ugly road trying to perform a CHECK with subqueries. As I found out (and you also mention in your answer), that is not even allowed in postgres: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179121/sql-sub-queries-in-check-constraint

This definitely appears to be the appropriate solution, as I have found virtually no one recommending the function "hack" to make a constraint. I've generally tried to avoid triggers, but it seems appropriate here.

Thank you for your help!