# PosgreSQL: Constraint Check that parent_id column doesn't contain any element of child_id column

Tags: postgresql

How to create a constraint check which ensures that parent_id column doesn't contain any element of child_id column ?

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT parent_cannot_be_child
CHECK (
  child_id NOT IN (
    SELECT parent_id FROM myschema.mytable
  )
)
```

But I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  cannot use subquery in check constraint
```

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179121/sql-sub-queries-in-check-constraint