# Java DB constraint

Tags: sql, constraints, derby

I'm trying to create a constraint in java DB. I have two tables: task and subtask. These tables have 1:m relationship (task 1:m subtask). The constraint need to check that the start_date in subtask is not earlier than the start date in the task table.
Not sure, how this can be done.
My code:

```
ALTER TABLE subtask
ADD CONSTRAINT c1 CHECK(
    s.start_date >= (SELECT t.start_date
                        FROM task t, subtask s
                        WHERE t.start_date = s.start_date)
)
```

This gives me error:
 `'subquery' may not appear in a CHECK CONSTRAINT definition because it may return non-deterministic results.`

How can I express the constraint in SQL? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't now about Derby but almost no DBMS (except Access which has issues) supports subqueries in `CHECK` constraints or (a similar concept) `ASSERTIONs` which are constraints that involve more than one tables (Firebird documentation says it does support these).

You can read some details about the difficulties involved in this fine answer: [Why don't DBMS's support ASSERTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368349/why-dont-dbmss-support-assertion)

---

One way to enforce your constraint declaratively is to add a (redundant) `task.start_date` column in table `subtask` as well and change the foreign key constraint to include that column. Sample table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE task
( task_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, task_start_date DATE NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT task_id_start_date_UQ
    UNIQUE (task_id, task_start_date)
) ;

CREATE TABLE subtask
( subtask_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, start_date DATE NOT NULL
, task_id INT NOT NULL
, task_start_date DATE NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT task_subtask_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (task_id, task_start_date)
    REFERENCES task (task_id, task_start_date)
, CONSTRAINT subtask_should_not_start_before_task_CK
    CHECK (start_date >= task_start_date)
) ;
```