# getting error: "could not find stored procedure" while making assertions

Tags: sql, sql-server, assertions

Im using microsoft sql server and Im learning basics of sql...
I have a table that contains name of patients and their primary doctors.
I want to check that a doctor can not be a primary doctor for more than 4 patients
here is what I have tried:

```
CREATE ASSERTION assertion12
(not exist(
select DOCTOR.SSN
from Patient, DOCTOR
where Patient.primaryDoctor_SSN = DOCTOR.SSN
group by DOCTOR.SSN
having count(primaryDoctor_SSN) >= 5
);
```

but I get the error in the first line: "could not find stored procedure" . (actually a red line comes under "CREATE" and shows this message )

What should I do?! I have check some sites and I saw writing assertions is like what I have done and I don't know why do I get this error.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you're trying to enforce that there's a maximum number of patients for any particular doctor? There *is* a way to do this declaratively in [SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23510713/15498) but I'm still not sure I'd recommend it. I'd probably still go down the trigger route to enforce such a constraint.

Comment: ALso see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6368349/27535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support `Create Assertion` , you can use a [Check Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) or [Create Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) as:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('assertion12','TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER assertion12;
GO
-- This trigger prevents a row from being inserted in the Patients table
-- when current patient's primary doctor already has patients = 4 (max 4)


CREATE TRIGGER assertion12 ON Patient
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS ( select count(P.primaryDoctor_SSN)
            from Patient P 
            JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON p.primaryDoctor_SSN = i.primaryDoctor_SSN 
            group by P.primaryDoctor_SSN
            having count(P.primaryDoctor_SSN) =4
          )
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Primary Doctor Assigned to the Patient already has 4 patients.', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN 
END;
GO

-- This statement attempts to insert a row into the Patient table
-- The AFTER INSERT trigger is fired and the INSERT transaction is rolled back.

INSERT INTO Patient values (5,1)
GO
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MHBKEK91810)</kbd>

Comment: I have a question. why do you write "join inserted as i"? I mean what is "inserted" here?!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not support `CREATE ASSERTION`.

In fact, no current SQL products support `CREATE ASSERTION` properly. Sybase SQL Anywhere supports it but reportedly has problems allowing constraints to sometimes be violated. [Rdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Rdb) did support it when it was looked after by DEC (who apparently were influential in the early days of the SQL standards, probably the reason why `CREATE ASSERTION` is in the standard in the first place) but that product is no more.

STOP PRESS: [according to their documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_assertions), HyperSQL (HSQLDB) supports assertions (though I'm left wondering why they don't shout about it on [their list of features](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFeatures.html)).

**Reference** [Does SQL Server 2008 support the CREATE ASSERTION syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130039/does-sql-server-2008-support-the-create-assertion-syntax/4131672#4131672)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know how can I check that this situation should not happen?! (without the command create assertion)